# Queryset that returns the data of a foreignkey relationship

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a query that returns the data of a foreignkey relationship, but I do not succeed. I want to bring the data of the web field of the Radio model to the query that I make of the model ProgramasRadiales. I only manage to bring the data from the Model ProgramasRadiales.

Models

```
class Radio(models.Model):
    usuario = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    radio = models.CharField('Nombre de la Emisora', max_length=50)
    web = models.URLField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['radio']
        verbose_name_plural = 'radios'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.radio

class ProgramasRadiales(models.Model):

    rango = (
            ('lun', 'Lunes'),
            ('mar', 'Martes'),
            ('mie', 'Miercoles'),
            ('jue', 'Jueves'),
            ('vie', 'Viernes'),
            ('sab', 'Sábado'),
            ('dom', 'Domingo')
        )

    nombre = models.CharField('Nombre del programa de radio', max_length=60)
    dias = MultiSelectField('Selecciona los días', choices = rango, max_length=40)
    inicio = models.TimeField(blank = False, null = True)
    duracion = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField('Duración del programa(minutos)', default=False)
    radios = models.ForeignKey(Radio)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['nombre']
        verbose_name_plural = 'programas radiales'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

Querys

```
datos = ProgramasRadiales.objects.all().values()
```

## result

```
<QuerySet [{'nombre': 'Matinal', 'inicio': datetime.time(10, 0), 'radios_id': 2, 'dias': ['mie'], 'duracion': 20, 'id': 3}, {'nombre': 'Nocturnos', 'inicio': datetime.time(18, 0), 'radios_id': 1, 'dias': ['jue', 'vie'], 'duracion': 20, 'id': 4}, {'nombre': 'Siempre Informados', 'inicio': datetime.time(6, 0), 'radios_id': 1, 'dias': ['lun', 'mie', 'vie'], 'duracion': 15, 'id': 2}, {'nombre': 'Tus noticias', 'inicio': datetime.time(7, 0), 'radios_id': 2, 'dias': ['lun', 'mar', 'mie', 'jue', 'vie'], 'duracion': 20, 'id': 1}]>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `select_related` on your query:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

```
datos = ProgramasRadiales.objects.select_related("radios").all()
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use '__' (double underscore operator) to get data of foreign key.

```
ProgramasRadiales.objects.all().values(
                               'nombre', 'inicio', 'radios__radio', 'radios__web')
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the explanation helped me.